# python - Pycharm ignores triple quotes around parameter

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm

Take the following script

```
import sys
for i in sys.argv:
    print(i)
```

I need `sys.argv` to contain the quote surrounding the parameter. To do that, when I execute this on Windows `cmd` I do

`python temp.py p1 p2 """p3"""`

Now here's the weird thing:

the output in `cmd` is

> p1 p2 "p3"

which is correct.

But when I execute it in Pycharm, populating `Script Parameters` with `p1 p2 """p3"""`, `sys.argv[3]` has no quotes around `p3` and the console output (inside Pycharm) also has no quotes around `p3`

> p1 p2 p3

How do I get Pycharm to respect the triple quote around the parameter?

```
PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.3
Build #PC-172.3968.37, built on September 1, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b11 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Comment: escape the quote with a backslash

Comment: @DmitryB. it works thanks.

Comment: I still think they should've kept the `cmd.exe python` behavior since that is what the `Script Parameters` is meant to emulate.

Comment: `cmd.exe` behavior is windows-specific. Since PyCharm runs on multiple platforms, it makes no sense to emulate the behavior of just one of the platforms.

Comment: @DmitryB. the whole point of script parameters is **what if you were to run this on the command line and pass these parameters** so it does make sense to follow the same behavior as the command line of the platform Pycharm is currently running on.

Comment: why do you think that's "the whole point"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not literally PyCharm problem. This is exactly the behavior of all Linux-like systems which use sh, bash, or alike.

To add the doule-quotes there, you have to escape each of them with the single quotes:

```
python temp.py p1 p2 '"'p3'"'
```

If you need to pass the single quote, you escape each of them with the double quotes:

```
python temp.py p1 p2 "'"p3"'"
```

If p3 itself can contain spaces or special chars, you have to escape it also with either single or double quotes:

```
python temp.py p1 p2 "'""p3""'"
python temp.py p1 p2 "'"'p3'"'"
```

To make it more clear, I'll put the braces, though it will not work with that way:

```
python temp.py p1 p2 ("'")("p3")("'")
python temp.py p1 p2 ("'")('p3')("'")
```

---

**UPD:** I was wrong. PyCharm does not follow the usual escaping of the script parameters as in the shell: neither cmd.exe, nor bash. It has its own rules. According to the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-python.html), you have to use the `\"`:

> - Use spaces to separate individual script parameters.
> - Script parameters containing spaces should be delimited with double quotes, for example, some" "param or "some param".
> - If script parameter includes double quotes, escape the double quotes with backslashes, for example:
>     `-s"main.snap_source_dirs=[\"pcomponents/src/main/python\"]"
>     -s"http.cc_port=8189" -s"backdoor.port=9189"`

So it will be:

```
python temp.py p1 p2 "\"p3\""
```

Comment: the whole point of script parameters is **what if you were to run this on the command line and pass these parameters** so it does make sense to follow the same behavior as the command line of the platform Pycharm is currently running on

Comment: @Adrian You are both right & wrong. Right because PyCharm does not follow the bash's escaping conventions. Wrong because PyCharm does not follow the platform's convention either, but has it own — I've added the link to the official documentation to the answer.